# Cannot connect externally to an ActiveMQ broker embedded in Jetty

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have a Jetty that starts an embedded ActiveMQ broker. I am trying to connect to it with JMSToolBox but I get the following exception:

```
Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:44523 failed: java.io.IOException: Unknown data type: 97
```

My code is as follows:

```
    File dataFileDir = new File("target/amq-in-action/kahadb");
    KahaDBStore kaha = new KahaDBStore();
    kaha.setDirectory(dataFileDir);
    kaha.setJournalMaxFileLength(1024 * 1204 * 100);
    kaha.setIndexWriteBatchSize(100);
    kaha.setEnableIndexWriteAsync(false);

    List<AuthenticationUser> users = new ArrayList<AuthenticationUser>();
    users.add(new AuthenticationUser(USER_NAME, PWD, "users,users_write"));
    SimpleAuthenticationPlugin simpleAuthenticationPlugin = new SimpleAuthenticationPlugin(users);
    simpleAuthenticationPlugin.setAnonymousAccessAllowed(false);

    List<DestinationMapEntry> authorizationEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    // giving permission to read the queue for users groups 
    AuthorizationEntry authorizationEntry = new AuthorizationEntry();
    authorizationEntry.setRead("users");
    authorizationEntry.setWrite("admins,users_write");
    authorizationEntry.setAdmin("admins");
    authorizationEntry.setQueue("Provisioning");
    authorizationEntries.add(authorizationEntry);
    // "Note that full access rights should generally be given to the ActiveMQ.Advisory destinations because by default an ActiveMQConnection uses destination advisors to get early knowledge of temp destination creation and deletion." -> http://activemq.apache.org/security.html
    authorizationEntry = new AuthorizationEntry();
    authorizationEntry.setRead("guests,users");
    authorizationEntry.setWrite("guests,users");
    authorizationEntry.setAdmin("guests,users");
    authorizationEntry.setTopic("ActiveMQ.Advisory.>");
    authorizationEntries.add(authorizationEntry);       
    AuthorizationMap authorizationMap = new DefaultAuthorizationMap(authorizationEntries);
    AuthorizationPlugin authorizationPlugin = new AuthorizationPlugin(authorizationMap);

    // creating the broker service
    broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.setPersistenceAdapter(kaha);
    broker.setUseJmx(false);
    broker.setPlugins(new BrokerPlugin[]{simpleAuthenticationPlugin, authorizationPlugin});
    broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");

    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
    new Resource(null, "java:/ConnectionFactory", connectionFactory);
    broker.start();
```

I'd presume I should be able to connect to the embedded queue from an external tool.
Any idea?

Thanks,
V.

Answer (score 1):

For [JMSToolBox](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox), JMX must be active, so please change

`broker.setUseJmx(false);`
by
`broker.setUseJmx(true); // This is the default..`

Also you may be interested in [this JMSToolBox issue](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/issues/17) that has a running example

Denis